# Best approach to pulling data from a SOAP service at regular intervals? - iPhone

Tags: ios, web-services, soap

I have an application which accesses a SOAP web service in order to download some of its data.  My problem is I need to perform this on a fairly regular basis.  Currently the user presses an 'update' button in order to download the data, but I would like it to be done without the user needing to press a button.

What would be the best approach to take in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as your downloading is already set up, it seems like all you need is to use an `NSTimer`.  For example, if you wanted it to trigger the download every thirty seconds you would put this line in:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(doDownload:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And you would have a function like

```
-(void) doDownload:(NSTimer*) timer
```

And if you are done with the downloads, within the `doDownload` function, you would call

```
[timer invalidate];
```

to shut off the timer.

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps need to clarify what do you mean by **I need to perform this on a fairly regular basis**. How frequent the update is required in your application(for example do you need the update every second, every minute, every hour....). Or it is not periodic and driven by server when there is an update available.

If you think the decision of updating the data is taken on server side implementation (for example something might have updated and server needs to update the client now) please consider using Apple's Push Notification system. If on the other hand, the update required is just periodic, think of a best trade off between frequency of data update and device' bandwidth/battery and go for it.